# Proc SQL (SAS) ; cómo recorrer y comparar el valor del score de un cliente por cada fecha de mi tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

Tengo un BD: Cliente, fecha ,Max, score donde el cliente tiene varios registros por fecha y para cada registro asignado un score y un flag (Max) como indicativo de ser el registro más reciente, quiero recorrer registro a registro de cada cliente y comparar si el último registro (última fecha), el score es diferente al inmediato anterior entonces lo cuento si no ( si es diferente) entonces compararlo con el registro antepenúltimo ,hasta llegar al mínimo y decidir si cuenta o no mi registro.